# Appending new values to a Matchcollection

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working with regular expression because I want to extract some data from a text file. For example I want to extract each number from this row in my text file:

```
ST/X   0.0000000000000000   6.4000000000000004   12.8000000000000010   19.1999999999999990   25.6000000000000010   32.0000000000000000
```

I 'm using this regular expression at the first to find **ST/X** to do that:

```
regstx.Pattern = "(ST/X)\s*(-?[\d]*(\.)?[\d]*\s*)+"
```

and then I find each number with this block of code:

```
If matchstx.Count <> 0 And (swknnf = True Or swknl = True) Then
 Set matchxnum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchstx.Item(0)), 5))
End If
```

I set regxnum like this:

```
regxnum.Pattern = "-?\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}"
```

It works fine If I only have one row of STX, but if I have many rows of STX after eaxh other like this:

```
ST/X   0.0000000000000000   6.4000000000000004   12.8000000000000010   19.1999999999999990   25.6000000000000010   32.0000000000000000   
ST/X   38.3999999999999990   44.7999999999999970   51.2000000000000030   57.6000000000000010   64.0000000000000000   70.4000000000000060
```

My idea doesn't work and the above code rewrite each STX, but I want to have all of STXs in *matchxnum* somehow I want to do so:

```
If matchstx.Count <> 0 And (swknnf = True Or swknl = True) Then
 Set matchxnum = matchxnum + regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(matchstx.Item(0)), 5))
End If
```

how can I implement this Idea in VBA, by the way, I have defined matchxnum like this and I'm usin VBA in access:

```
DIM matchxnum As MatchCollection
```

would you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your issue is that your `matchxnum` collection is being overwritten for each input line you process then a simple solution would be to create your own collection and append the members of `matchxnum` to it after each `regxnum.Execute()` call, something like this

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject, ts As TextStream, tsLine As String
Dim regxnum As New RegExp, matchxnum As MatchCollection, matchxnumItem As match
Dim myCollection As New Collection, thing As Variant

Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\__tmp\stxTest.txt", ForReading)

regxnum.Pattern = "-?\d{1,}\.{0,1}\d{0,}"
regxnum.Global = True

Do While Not ts.AtEndOfStream
    tsLine = ts.ReadLine
    Set matchxnum = regxnum.Execute(Mid(Trim(tsLine), 5))
    For Each matchxnumItem In matchxnum
        '' append this group of matches to a separate Collection
        myCollection.Add matchxnumItem.Value
    Next
Loop

'' now dump the contents of myCollection to make sure the code worked
For Each thing In myCollection
    Debug.Print thing
Next
```